# Button not working when running app in real device in android studio

Tags: android, button, android-volley

I am making login and signup activity in android studio with php and mysql. The button and all works fine in android emulator, but when i am running and clicking the login button in the real device, nothing happens

Login activity

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText Login_Mob,Login_Pwd;
    TextView Login_signup_here,Login_Forget_Pwd;
    Button Login_Button;
    CheckBox showPWD;
    private static String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/app2/login.php";
    Context context;
    SharedPreferences sp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        Login_Mob =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_lnmobioe);
        Login_Pwd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_lnpassword);
        Login_signup_here=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_signuphere);
        showPWD=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.show_pwd);
        Login_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        Login_signup_here.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,Signup.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        showPWD.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    Login_Pwd.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                }
                Login_Pwd.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());

            }
        });
        Login_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String Login_UserMob=Login_Mob.getText().toString();
                String Login_UserPass=Login_Pwd.getText().toString();


                if (Login_UserMob.equalsIgnoreCase("")||
                        Login_UserPass.equalsIgnoreCase("")||Login_UserPass.length()>=5)
                {
                    if (Login_UserMob.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                        Login_Mob.setError("Enter your mobile No ");
                    }
                    else if(Login_UserPass.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                        Login_Pwd.setError("Enter your password");
                    }
                    else{
                        if(Constants.isOnline(getApplicationContext())){
                            login(LOGIN_URL, Login_UserMob, Login_UserPass);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Entries are Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private void login(String loginUrl, final String login_userMob, final String login_userPass) {
        RequestQueue requestQueue=new Volley().newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        StringRequest postRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, loginUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                    if(jsonObject.getInt("success")==1)
                    {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Going to Profile Info Signup", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        JSONObject jsonObjectInfo=jsonObject.getJSONObject("User");
                        Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,ProfileInfoSignup.class);
                     //   intent.putExtra("name",jsonObjectInfo.getString("name"));
                        intent.putExtra("email",jsonObjectInfo.getString("email"));
                        intent.putExtra("mobile",jsonObjectInfo.getString("mobile"));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        })

        {
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String, String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();
                param.put("mobile", login_userMob);
                param.put("password",login_userPass);
                return param;
            }

        };
        int socketTimeout = 30000;
        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        postRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        requestQueue.add(postRequest);
    }
}
```

log

```
08-04 13:51:43.761 21964-21964/? W/subsystem_ramdu: type=1400 audit(0.0:17275): avc: denied { search } for name="/" dev="sdcardfs" ino=229377 scontext=u:r:subsystem_ramdump:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:sdcardfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
08-04 13:51:43.774 21964-21964/? I/subsystem_ramdump: Usage:./system/bin/subsystem_ramdump [arg1] [arg2] [arg3]
    [arg1]: (1/2) Ramdump location: 1: eMMC: /data/ramdump or 2: SD card: /sdcard/ramdump
    [arg2]: (1/0) 1: Enable RPM log / 0: Disable RPM log
    [arg3]: (1/0) 1: Enable qdss ramdump / 0: Disable qdss ramdump
08-04 13:51:43.775 21964-21964/? E/subsystem_ramdump: Directory /sdcard/ramdump does not exist
08-04 13:51:43.775 21964-21964/? I/subsystem_ramdump: Attemping to create /sdcard/ramdump
08-04 13:51:43.776 21964-21964/? E/subsystem_ramdump: Unable to create /sdcard/ramdump
    Unable to create /sdcard/ramdump
    Failed to initialize ramdump
08-04 13:51:43.761 21964-21964/? W/subsystem_ramdu: type=1400 audit(0.0:17276): avc: denied { search } for name="/" dev="sdcardfs" ino=229377 scontext=u:r:subsystem_ramdump:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:sdcardfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
```

Does this have anything to do with device or something else ?
Any help will be deeply appreciated

Comment: Dubug your code, maybe you get `VolleyError error`

Comment: Have you included the permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml`, and granted them on the device?

Comment: which permission?

Comment: Please paste the full "logcat"! It's not clear-enough with the current pasted.